# Applying a predicate to a subset of a list in Prolog: requesting advice on implementation choices

Tags: performance, list, prolog, filtering, tail-recursion

**Edit:** There seems to have been some understandable confusion by me using the terms 1st and 2nd implementation referring to them in the order they were listed, after I had mentioned that the 2nd one listed was the first I tried implementing, so I reworded the relevant paragraphs. Sorry for the confusion.

Some motivational background: I am building a constraint solver in SWI Prolog, and to greatly optimize space and time, I've built a reverse index into the main constraint data structures. Whenever a "variable" in my system (not a Prolog variable) is assigned a value, I want to make sure this assignment does not make any other constraints unsatisfiable. I have an index from variables to constraints to quickly select the constraints to check. As some point, this boils down to applying a try_check/2 predicate to a given left-hand-side (LHS) and to all the elements of a right-hand-side list (RHS_L) whose indexes appear in a list (IdxL). Here's my current implementation:

```
%% FORALL Implementation
try_check_filtered(LHS, IdxL, RHS_L) :-
    forall((member(Idx, IdxL), nth0(Idx, RHS_L, RHS)), 
           try_check(LHS, RHS)).
```

I also have an earlier implementation which does the same thing, but takes an additional argument at the 2nd position to keep track of the current list index (the list of indexes is sorted in ascending order):

```
%% Tail-Recursive Implementation
%%try_check_filtered(+LHS, +Idx, +IdxL, +RHS_L)
try_check_filtered(_LHS, _Idx, [], _RHS_L) :- !.    % Stop when index list is empty
try_check_filtered(LHS, Idx, [Idx|Ti], [H|T]) :- !, % If at next index -> check
    try_check(LHS, H),
    Inext is Idx+1,
    try_check_filtered(LHS, Inext, Ti, T).
try_check_filtered(LHS, Idx, IdxL, [_H|T]) :-       % If not at next index -> skip
    Inext is Idx+1,
    try_check_filtered(LHS, Inext, IdxL, T).
try_check_filtered(_LHS, _Idx, _IdxL, []).           % Done when at the end of RHS_L
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to implement this that I can't think of?
2. I was surprised to find that the forall implementation performs better than the tail-recursive one. In my mind, the tail-recursive has a linear time dispatch (walks down the list once to "call" all the necessary try_check), whereas the forall implementation has quadratic dispatch (linear number of calls to member, each causing another linear call to nth0). (If you're curious about the performance improvement I saw, in an execution that takes ~44s, using the forall implementation over the tail-recursive on saves about 4s).

One thought I had was that the tail-recursion optimization was not applied to my tail-recursive implementation, forcing multiple copies of the lists onto stack frames, thus making it slower.
In order to (hopefully) enable the tail-recursion optimization for my tail-recursive implementation, I tried to make my try_check/2 predicate deterministic by adding a cut (!) right at the end of the rule. Is that enough? Does it matter that the try_check/2 rule has temporary side effects: it asserts some facts, which it retracts before finishing, thus leaving the collection of facts unchanged. The performance I reported above was with the cut in the try_check/2 predicate.

I hope I gave sufficient information to have a constructive discussion. Thank you in advance for the replies!

**Edit:** Here's the (high level) implementation of try_check. The entire code is 2600 lines, many of which (probably half) are indirectly used by this check, so it is not possible to post here.

```
%% try_check_eni(+E1:effect, +E2:effect)
try_check_eni(E1, E2) :-
    push_trying,
    check_no_try,
    ( is_non_interfering(E1, E2)
    -> (clear_try, pop_trying)
    ; (clear_try, pop_trying, fail))
    , !.
```

`push_trying/0` and `pop_trying/0` assert and retract a `trying/0` predicate which slightly modifies how some of the other predicates operate, so that I wouldn't have to duplicate the code used by checking predicates for the try_check predicates. `is_non_interfering/2` is non-deterministic. In `trying` mode, `is_non_interfering` marks instantiated variables as `try/1` so that the instantiation can be retracted by `clear_try/0` after the constraint is checked.

Answer (score 2):

`nth0/3` has linear costs. Thus, the combination with `member/2` and `forall/2` has quadratic costs. In fact the second code variant does not take any advantage of the fact that the list of indices is in ascending order, while the first one does.

Try not to over-optimize at this stage of development: first perform right, then (and only then) perform fast.

Focus on clean readable code, choose the proper data-structures, make the right library choices... If the circumstances demand it, you could then replace random read accesses in lists with, say, some compound structures plus `arg/3`.

Also, your code might profit from first-argument indexing. Be careful when using cut and/or assert/retract, both can easily drag down correctness *and* performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I realized my post wasn't clear. In using the terms 1st and 2nd implementation I was referring to the order in which they were listed in the question, not the chronological order in which I had implemented them. So I was (still am) confused as to why the quadratic version (forall) is outperforming the linear one (tail-recursive).

Comment: Hi repeat. I edited the question to add some of the info you requested. Unfortunately, there is just too much code to provide a full implementation. It is a solver with relatively complex rules for deciding satisfiability due to the domain (look up deterministic parallel java, or DPJ, if you're interested). I hope the info I provided is at least somewhat helpful.